# Can I use mysqli in wamp without having to pay for web hosting?

Tags: php, mysqli, wampserver

Can I use mysqli in wamp without having to pay for web hosting, just like I can use mysql in wamp without having to pay for web hosting? and if so, please help me see the light.

PS: I only want to pay for hosting when my site is ready. but I cant seem to use mysqli in wamp, like I can use mysql. and I dont want to use mysql

Thanks

Comment: which hosting service uses wamp?

Comment: I'm building my site with Wamp, but will have to choose a web host for the site when it's done. #sorry I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be running PHP 5.29 or higher. If you are not, update PHP first. If you are running that version or higher, or after you upgrade, follow these steps:

1. Left click wamp manager icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions
2. Click and select the php_mysqli extension
3. Restart all services in WAMP

Comment: My PHP version is 5.5.12. It's the latest version.

Comment: Ok, will do it then. Thanks